# Redirect a specific request to another domain

Tags: java, c++, redirect

I am making a private server for a game, and I need to redirect all requests from http://crossfire.z8games.com/ to (let's say) http://cfire.v1k.me/ but only while the redirection program is running. I need some suggestions and what language this is best done (in java/c++, etc.)

I don't want to hex edit program, because I want the user to easily switch between my server and the original server.

So, again, I want some suggestions and code examples on how to simply redirect xxx.xx to yyy.yy with a simple application without modifying the hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to check for an error when connecting to the first url.  If an error happens, then you try the second one.

[Here's an example that shows how to connect to one url.](http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-simple-httpurlconnection-example.html)  In the `catch` blocks, that's where you should try to connect to the second url.

Comment: Okay, I think that you misunderstood me. Okay, let's say there is an application "game.exe" that connects to http://xxx.com/, I want to redirect the requests for game.exe to http://yyy.com/

Comment: And I doubt every user will want to download and install Apache.